# How to get android:configChanges values from ActivityInfo class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-package-managers

I would like to fetch activities info(Such as configchanges, resizemode, if Picture in Picture is supported) of all the packages present in the device.

I am able to fetch the activities info using `PackageManager` with `GET_ACTIVITIES` flag. With that I can get `configChanges` value using `ActivityInfo.configChanges`.

However the value returns a random int if there are multiple config values set in `android:configChanges`.

For ex:

if below values are set

> android:configChanges="uiMode|smallestScreenSize|locale|colorMode|density"

Getting configchanges value using below code

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

ActivityInfo activityInfo[] = packageInfo.activities;

if(activityInfo!=null) {
    for(ActivityInfo activity : activityInfo) {
      int configChange = activity.configChanges;
    }
}
```

I get `activity.configChanges` value as 23047

What does 23047 denotes, how do I decode it so that I can get the config values that are set in `AndroidManifest.xml`

In Addition to that is there any way we can get `activity.resizeMode` . I understand that it is `@hide` api. I can see the value in debugging mode though in Android Studio.

Any leads/help to above will be really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configChanges` is a bit mask.

To check if a given bit is set, you simply need to use an appropriate [bitwise operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

For example, to check if `uiMode` is set you could do something like this:

```
int configChanges = activityInfo.configChanges;

if ((configChanges & ActivityInfo.CONFIG_UI_MODE) == ActivityInfo.CONFIG_UI_MODE) {
    // uiMode is set
} else {
    // uiMode is not set
}
```

Defining a method might make it easier:

```
public boolean isConfigSet(int configMask, int configToCheck) {
    return (configMask & configToCheck) == configToCheck;
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
int configChanges = activityInfo.configChanges;

boolean uiModeSet = isConfigSet(configChanges, ActivityInfo.CONFIG_UI_MODE);
boolean colorModeSet = isConfigSet(configChanges, ActivityInfo.CONFIG_COLOR_MODE);
// ...
```

> In Addition to that is there any way we can get `activity.resizeMode` .
>   I understand that it is `@hide` api.

Reliably, no. You might be able to access it through the reflection API, although Google released a [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/improving-stability-by-reducing-usage.html) recently stating the following:

> Starting in the next release of Android, some non-SDK methods and
>   fields will be restricted so that you cannot access them -- either
>   directly, via reflection, or JNI.

(accessing hidden fields via reflection is strongly discouraged anyway)